# Google Forms regex validation for proper name

Tags: regex, google-forms

Trying to validate strings such as...

- My Company Name *(pass)*
- my ComPany name *(fail)*
- my Company Name *(fail)*
- my company name *(fail)*
- MY Company Name *(pass)*
- COMPANY *(pass)*

Want it to match a proper name format ***(caps on first letter of each word)***...

- My Company Name

I can use the following regex and it works great over at https://regex101.com/.  But when I try to use it in a Google Form validation it does **NOT** work.  I think Google does not like the `\p` flags.

```
^([\p{Lu}]\p{L}*\s*)+$
```

Is there a way to convert that to a regex that does not use the `\p` flag?  I tried the following regex string and it did **NOT** do the trick either...

```
^([[A-Z]][a-z]*\s*)+$
```

Comment: Did `^([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$` not work with Google Forms or it does not suit your needs (why?)

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en

Comment: @kit Dear lord!  I swear I tested the hell out if it and it wouldn't work...  Yet as soon as I type it here I guess my butterfingers didn't get the best of me...  Gezz..  To answer your question it seems to work great.  Put it in an answer.  ;)

Comment: It will match `MYy Company Name` which is incorrect and also `My ComPany Name`

Comment: @rock321987 Another correction: ^([A-Z]+\s+)?([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$
(\s+ instead of \s*)
Arvo Bowen, if it works for you, I will correct my answer

Comment: @kit it still won't work

Comment: @rock321987 Commented before your edit, haven't seen My ComPany Name yet

Comment: @kit test it properly..don't be in a hurry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't necessary need Unicode, try this:
`^(([A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+))(\s+(([A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)))*$`

Each word may look like `COMPANY` or `Company`, but not like `company`, with spaces between words (after the 2nd).

**Matches**: `My Company Name, MY COMPANY Name, COMPANY`.
**Does not match**: `my ComPany name, my Company Name, my company name`.

`(([A-Z]+)` matches ALL UPPERCASE
`([A-Z][a-z]+)` matches Capitalized
`(...)|(...)` matches first **or** second group
`*` allows 0 or many `Words` after the first word
`\s+` matches one or multiple spaces before words after the 2nd
`^` - start of string, `$` - end of string

A simpler solution if `MyCompanyName` and `MYCOMPANy` are also acceptable (first letter capitalized):
`^([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$`

Tested with regex101

Comment: Does it match `COMPANY` ?

Comment: Actually testing over at https://regex101.com/ it would not match "My Company Name" and I need it to.

Comment: Corrected my regexp, check it

Comment: @kit do you think `^([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$` would work just as well or do you think it needs to be `^([A-Z]+\s*)?([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$`?  I ask because the first one is much smaller.

Comment: @ArvoBowen the first one will actually work the same as the second, now that I corrected the second a bunch of times.

Comment: @ArvoBowen is `MY COMPANY Name` acceptable or all-uppercase might be on the first word only?

Comment: Try this: `^(([A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+))(\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*$`. Works if uppercase word might be only the first one. Works with `My Company Name`, `MY Company Name`, 'COMPANY`, does not pass `my Company`, `my company` and `my ComPany`

Comment: @kit yes, `MY COMPANY Name` is acceptable. But NOT `MY COMPANY name`.  The point of the validation was a simple check to see if they have the first letter capitalized in each word.  They could possibly have `My CoMpaNy NaMe` for all I care.  Some company name's are displayed weird and I accept that.  But they will be proper about it.  ;)

Comment: @kit I'm going to accept your answer, though I think you should add `^([A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+$` to your answer for simplicity.  It seems to work perfectly! - Thanks for the answer!

Comment: your regex is still not correct and not meeting the OP's requirement.. Correct it please.. Give it one more shot

Comment: Could this include something like: ```My O'Company```?

Answer (score 3):

This regex will work

```
^(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*))(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*))*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF3qR7/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*)) #Match at least one group starting with alphabets [A-Z]
(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*))* #Check whatever follows contains space and meets the same requirement as above
$ #End of string
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although I think this answer was much more then needed it was a great one.  I love the Regex Demo you added to the answer too!